# nginx mirror directive not working

Tags: nginx, proxy, mirroring

I am trying to mirror a request that coming to one of our services, nginx is acting as the web server.
I've used the mirror directive to proxy the requests to an AWS ALB, but it seems that nginx is not copying the request to the ALB.

```
server {
listen       80;
server_name  service-01.example;
root         /srv/www/apps/service-01/public;

location / {
    mirror /mirror;
    try_files $uri @app;
     }
location @app {
    uwsgi_pass unix:/run/uwsgi-apps/service-01.sock;
    uwsgi_read_timeout 300s;

    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_param UWSGI_SCHEME $scheme;
    uwsgi_modifier1 5;}

     location /mirror {
        internal;
        proxy_pass http://aws-alb$request_uri;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `proxy_pass` directive in the `/mirror` location block should not include the `$request_uri`, the mirrored request's URI is preserved by default.

I modified your configuration like that:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  service-01.example;
    root         /srv/www/apps/service-01/public;

    location / {
        mirror /mirror;
        try_files $uri @app;
    }

    location @app {
        uwsgi_pass unix:/run/uwsgi-apps/service-01.sock;
        uwsgi_read_timeout 300s;

        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_param UWSGI_SCHEME $scheme;
        uwsgi_modifier1 5;
    }

    location /mirror {
        internal;
        proxy_pass http://aws-alb; # Remove the $request_uri variable
    }
}
```